# Can I call an IO-bound Python function from multiple Rust threads concurrently?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I have a Python function that can be slow, so I need to be able to run that function concurrently. If I were running the Python script directly, I'd simply create multiple threads and so I would be able to easily run that function concurrently. I must use CPython, but GIL is not an issue, as my function is IO-bound (not CPU-bound).

I know I can run a Python function from Rust via libraries like [PyO3](https://crates.io/crates/pyo3) and [rust-cpython](https://crates.io/crates/cpython). But I haven't been able to find a way to run that Python function *concurrently* from multiple Rust threads.

Python Subinterpreters are still experimental, AFAIK, so maybe my only option would be to somehow spawn multiple Python threads, but how do I then access them without being exclusively locked by the Rust's library GIL "wrapper"...? Is that possible at all?

Comment: What's wrong with calling `Python::with_gil` from multiple threads? I assume that as soon as the Python code in one thread releases the GIL, the other threads will be able to acquire it and proceed.